# Want to optimize mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I am looking for help in optimizing  this mysql query. Takes a super long time to run because both tables under main_activity are massive ( over 10 million rows each! ). The main_db.members and main_db.customers are about 400K and 600K rows respectively.

EDIT:

Based on the suggestions to use a temp table, just want to add that I am running the query on a read only database so the temp table might be an issue. What optimization  can I do without using a temp table?

```
select distinct
    a.members_id,
    a.customer_id,
    a.subscription,
    a.buy_date,
    from_unixtime((max(m2.sales_date) / 1000), '%m/%d/%Y')  as sales_date,
    a.return_date,
    a.signup_date,
    from_unixtime((max(st.visit_date) / 1000), '%m/%d/%Y') as visit_date
from (select distinct
          m1.members_id,
          m1.customer_id,
          m1.subscription,
          from_unixtime((m1.buy_date / 1000), '%m/%d/%Y') as buy_date,
          from_unixtime((m1.return_date / 1000), '%m/%d/%Y')   as return_date,
          from_unixtime((c.signup_date / 1000), '%m/%d/%Y')   as signup_date
      from main_db.members m1
          join main_db.customer c on c.global_members_id = m1.members_id
     ) as a
    left join main_db.members m2 on m2.customer_id = a.customer_id
    left join main_activity.onlinevisit s on s.customer_id = a.customer_id
    left join main_activity.storevisit st on st.visit_id = s.visit_id
```

Comment: I was using max to pull the last sales date and last store visit date from the various other tables.  I needed to extract just the last date in each case. There are several values for store visits and sales dates assigned to each customer and member id. The other fields didn't need to be aggregated

Comment: @GordonLinoff Welcome to MySQL ;)

Comment: at least include the explain plan https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html

Comment: beside the crazyness of mysql group by, your query looks ok. So the most posible issue is proper index on the tables involve in the query. Check the explain plan

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to create a temporary table with a good key. We can start with this:

```
create temporary table a (key(customer_id)) select distinct
          m1.members_id,
          m1.customer_id,
          m1.subscription,
          from_unixtime((m1.buy_date / 1000), '%m/%d/%Y') as buy_date,
          from_unixtime((m1.return_date / 1000), '%m/%d/%Y')   as return_date,
          from_unixtime((c.signup_date / 1000), '%m/%d/%Y')   as signup_date
      from main_db.members m1
          join main_db.customer c on c.global_members_id = m1.members_id;


select distinct
    a.members_id,
    a.customer_id,
    a.subscription,
    a.buy_date,
    from_unixtime((max(m2.sales_date) / 1000), '%m/%d/%Y')  as sales_date,
    a.return_date,
    a.signup_date,
    from_unixtime((max(st.visit_date) / 1000), '%m/%d/%Y') as visit_date
from a
    left join main_db.members m2 on m2.customer_id = a.customer_id
    left join main_activity.onlinevisit s on s.customer_id = a.customer_id
    left join main_activity.storevisit st on st.visit_id = s.visit_id;
```

You will need to make sure you have good keys in other tables as well.

Comment: Yes, an index that can actually be used for the query. You probably need a key on customer_id in the s table and m2 table, and on visit_id in the st table. To find out if all the keys are there, run EXPLAIN on the last query.

Comment: Again you mean `INDEX` like https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html When you say Key sound like `Primary Key` those have index or `Foreign Key` those doesnt have index by default,  also other fields can have Index.

Comment: `KEY` is a synonym for `INDEX` in MySQL for many things, including in alter table statements. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html and how you can indicate either keyword. Sasha's use of the word key is not incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

I hope there are indexes on

```
m2.customer_id
s.customer_id
st.visit_id
```

If not, that could be a significant performance problem.

The use of `DISTINCT` implies that the `JOINs` are multiplying the number of rows, and you need to deflate it.  Does each query work ok without `DISTINCT`?  Eliminating it would save a pass over the data.

Another possibility for avoiding the inflation-deflation overhead is replacing

```
max(m2.sales_date)
```

with

```
( SELECT max(m2.sales_date)
      FROM main_db.members m2
      WHERE m2.customer_id = a.customer_id )
```

(etc)